# Not able to run my app on my physical iPhone device?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, xcode11

I was building an app it is working in simulator and than I tried to run it on my physical iPhone device it is working But the Problem is when I open that app later on
I mean when I run that app in Xcode than it launches correctly on my physical iPhone everything works fine but when I try to open it manually on my iPhone it disappears in a second

I can't upload the video of the problem so here is the link to my tweet which contains the video please help me with this https://twitter.com/AgarkarYuvraj/status/1352663778345717763?s=20

And this is happening only with this particular app

Some extra info : I am not using any external dependencies or cocoa pods
I am running on iOS 14.3
I am using background locations

Comment: Have you got a paid Developer Membership with Apple?

Comment: @matt , No I haven't but that doesn't matter because I just tested it like 2min after , I mean as soon as I try to open it manually (means without running from Xcode )I happens this way

Comment: "but that doesn't matter" Yes, it does. It is _exactly_ what matters. You have no ability to run the app by opening it manually; that is part of what you get by paying the $100/year fee. Do you see?

Comment: @matt , but I was able to do it before , like as far as I know the app expired in 7 days earlier , and before(like 20 days ago) I installed the same on my phone and it was working , have this policies changed lately??

Comment: so you want to run this app on a real iOS device without being connected to Xcode, right? So your iOS device are unplugged and then you are trying to open it, am I correct?

Comment: @Asol , yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would try to reconnect your app?
By reconnecting I mean to set a connection between your device and Xcode **absolutely** **newly**.
And ofc, to make sure your device trusts your computer.

Plus, try to clean the Xcode cache since it can be a reason why it happens.
You may refer to this article https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-xcode-cache

Let me know if anything suggested helped you.

Comment: Hey I just tested and found out that its happening only with this particular app and not with any other. I have tried the above mentioned things but dose't work